# How to create a resizable and movable div in wrapper div in react.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, resize, movable

This is what I need:
[image]

[image]

So, this lightblue div needs to be:

- resizable (on the left and right side, cannot resize over lightgray wrapper div width), and
- movable inside lightgray wrapper div (cannot overflow its sides).

On his sides, lightblue div needs to have cursor: ew-resize; and inside needs to be cursor: grab.

I tried so many things but I didnt success to do both functionalities, I have separately resizing and moving... Also, I don't use any library for it.

How to achieve that in js and react.js?

Please help if someone know!

Comment: but after that what are you doing with it?

Comment: i think the idea to solve this problem is to do it with simple javascript first then transform it into reactjs

Comment: @mayacohen That scrolling and resizing affect on some view above the tracking div, but I have functionality for it so that is ok.